# Which one is the correct Maven phase to download something necessary for compilation?

Tags: maven

I tried `process-sources` but is sounds wrong to me, because I need the moment before anything gets done with the source code.

Comment: perhaps `generate-sources` ?

Comment: I do not know your use case, but relying on external downloads does not sound like a maven conform way of preparing a build. Did you consider packaging your dependency as a maven artifact?

Comment: What is it you that need to download for compilation?

Comment: @vikingsteve Source code generation can require other source code. Do I have to use `validate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three earlier phases earlier in the [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) before `process-sources` that could be used:

> 1. validate → validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available.
> 2. initialize → initialize build state, e.g. set properties or create directories.
> 3. generate-sources → generate any source code for inclusion in compilation.

From the documentation, I would choose the `validate` phase based on the "necessary information is available" part.

Or you could create your own phase - see [Creating a new phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433120/maven-creating-a-new-phase)

Answer (score 1):

You may use initialize, this is just before anything related to sources, as explained here : 
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference