# Maven: lifecycle.xml or lifecycles.xml?

Tags: maven, lifecycle

I'm a little confused by the Maven documentation - should lifecycles be defined in lifecycles.xml or lifecycle.xml? Even the Sonatype reference talks about these two names seemingly interchangeably!

Still confused about components.xml too - if there's any good reference for that can you post it please?

Thanks,
-Dave

Comment: What about [lifecycle documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-plugin-api/lifecycle-mappings.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `lifecycle.xml` (see [Lifecycle Mappings](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-plugin-api/lifecycle-mappings.html)):

> Configuration of custom lifecycle mappings for the plugin, as generally stored in `META-INF/maven/lifecycle.xml` in a plugin's jar artifact.

`lifecycles.xml`, with an 's', appears [only once in the Maven source, commented out](https://github.com/apache/maven/commit/560d47dccb8423cda5f619e118eb71de45259989#diff-0d5db32381f7151d13562e26920316bbR64) as a distinct and never-used file.

Also, `components.xml`, as in [Overriding the Default Lifecycle](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html#writing-plugins-sect-override-default-lifecycle):

> In your plugin project, create a `META-INF/plexus/components.xml` under `src/main/resources`.

See [Creating a new phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433120/creating-a-new-phase) for a full example.